# How to list the current set of words in Forth

Tags: forth, gforth

Is it possible to get the list of all words which are currently defined in Forth (for example in [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth))?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard `WORDS` word prints all the words from the top vocabulary (wordlist) only — see the [specification](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools/WORDS) .

[TRAVERSE-WORDLIST](http://www.forth200x.org/traverse-wordlist.html) proposal defines API to enumerate words in given wordlist. Some Forth-systems already implemented this proposal ([update] it is already in the [draft](https://forth-standard.org/standard/tools/TRAVERSE-WORDLIST)).

Although there is no standard API to enumerate all defined wordlists. [`GET-ORDER`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/search/GET-ORDER) gives a list of the context wordlists only (i.e. wordlists in the scope).

Some Forth-systems have `VOCS` word that prints all defined vocabularies.
Other possible APIs are specific for particular Forth-system. For example, SP-Forth has `ENUM-VOCS` word to enumerate all known wordlists.